# Why isn't $\oint_{C} f(z) = 2\pi i\, \mathrm{d}z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I was going over some practice problems

> **T/F:** If $C$ is the circle in $\mathbb{C}$ of radius $10$ centered at $z=2i$ with positive orientation and
>   $$f(z) = \frac{\cos(4z)}{z}$$
>   then
>   $$ \oint_{C} f(z) \mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i\, \mathrm{}.$$

I used the Cauchy Integral Theorem, with $z_0= 0$ and $f(z)= \cos(4z)$. That gives the value as $2\pi i$, but the answer is given as false? What mistake am I making?

Comment: @Fakemistake - OP got that answer, but was told the answer was something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so let's try another technique to verify your answer. Your curve $C$ can be parameterized by $z(t) = 10e^{it} + 2i$ for $t \in [0,2\pi)$. Then your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(40e^{it} + 8i)}{10e^{it} + 2i} \cdot 10ie^{it} \cdot dt$$

Obviously this isn't something you want to bother calculating through this method. But WolframAlpha can approximate it (as seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%2840e%5E%7Bit%7D+%2B+8i%29%7D%7B10e%5E%7Bit%7D+%2B+2i%7D+*+10ie%5E%7Bit%7D+*+dt)), and returns an answer of about $6.28319i$. This obviously is quite close to $2\pi i$.

With this in mind, and the fact that I see nothing wrong with your approach (though you shouldn't say $f(z) = \cos(4z)/z$ and then also have $f(z) = \cos(4z)$ represent the numerator), I assume the answer is in error.